# Promise doesn't wait before passing to next function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to insert all transactions into a database after I've parsed them. 
I have a function called load.newload(transactionlist); which is passed after baby parse finishes parsing.

I've tested my code, and it loads all the files if the file list is short, but once it gets long (around 10 files or more), it calls the load.newload(transactionlist) function even before it finished parsing.

I was thinking maybe I should have another promise for the baby.parse function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Results look like this:

parse file1,
parse file2,
parse file3,
SQL connected,
Insert data successful,
parse file4,
parse file5

How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
var baby = require('babyparse');
var read = require('read-file');
var Promise = require('promise');
var load = require('../sql/insert');
var transactionlist = [];
var incomingfile = function(file){
     //async load file and then parse after loading
        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              read( file, 'utf8', function (err, res){
              if (err) 
                {reject(err);
                console.log('Oops, an error occured while parsing the data: %s', err);}
              else {resolve(res);
                    console.log(file);}
            });
        }).then(function (results){
                var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                baby.parse(results , {
                    dynamicTyping: true,
                    delimiter: "|",
                    complete: function (results, error) {
                        if(error)
                        {console.log('Something went wrong');
                         reject(error);}
                        else {
                              for(i = 1; i < results.data.length - 1; i++)
                                {
                                    var transaction  = {
                                        column1 : results.data[i][14].substring(0, 6),
                                        column2: results.data[i][2].split(' ').join(''),
                                        column3: results.data[i][14].split(' ').join(''),
                                        column4: results.data[i][8],
                                        column5: results.data[i][9]
                                    }
                                    transactionlist.push(transaction);
                                }//end for loop
                                resolve(results);
                                }
                        //console.log("Finished:", JSON.stringify(results.data));
                    }//end baby parse complete:function
                    });//end baby parse function
                }).then(function (results){
                    load.newload(transactionlist);
            });//end inner .then function
        });//end .then function
}//end incoming file function


exports.incomingfile = incomingfile;


//newload function in insert.js
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
var config = require('../connect');
var newload = function (transactionlist){
            sql.connect(config)
              .then(() => {
                console.log('connected');
                    const table = new sql.Table('settlement');
                    table.create = true;
                    //table.columns.add('transactionid', sql.Int, { nullable: false, primary: true});
                    table.columns.add('colum1', sql.VarChar(6), { nullable: false });
                    table.columns.add('column2', sql.VarChar(50), { nullable: false });
                    table.columns.add('column3', sql.VarChar(50), { nullable: false });
                    table.columns.add('column4', sql.VarChar(50), { nullable: false });
                    table.columns.add('column5', sql.VarChar(5), { nullable: false });

                     //add here rows to insert into the table
                    for (i = 0; i < transactionlist.length; i++) {

                        table.rows.add(transactionlist[i].column1, transactionlist[i].column2, transactionlist[i].column3, transactionlist[i].column4, transactionlist[i].column5);
                        console.log('transaction list', i , JSON.stringify(transactionlist.length));
                      }     
                const request = new sql.Request();
                console.log('Ready to insert data');
                request.bulk(table, function (error, results){
                    if(error)
                    {
                        console.log('Something went wrong while inserting the data into the database');
                        sql.close();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Data has been inserted successfully');
                        sql.close();
                    }
                })  
              });
};

exports.newload = newload;
```

Comment: `incomingfile` function doesn't return anything - by the way - 48 lines of **actual** code spread out of 91 lines makes reading your code more difficult than necessary

Comment: quick fix (I think, for reasons outlined above) change the two occurences of `var promise = new Promise ... etc` to `return new Promise ... etc`

Comment: @JaromandaX: apologies for that. I have difficult time reading when there aren't any spaces. I've just tried what you said, and still yields the same results

Comment: @JaromandaX: incoming file does return something as I am only having a problem inserting the last file into the DB. If it didn't return anything, I wouldn't have been able to insert since the start?

Comment: `incoming file does return something` the function incomingFile? what does it return? `undefined` - I may have misunderstood how `incomingFile` is **actually** used - as is, it's return value is not useful

Comment: OK, re-read the question, and `load.newload(transactionlist);` will not wait for `baby.parse` to complete due to the fact that the first `}).then(function (results){` doesn't return anything either - i.e. if you changed the code like I suggested, problem should be solved

Comment: @JaromandaX: I don't think you read my comment. I DID change it to what you suggested and it's EXACTLY the same results as I currently have. It's only passing some transactions to load.newload(transactionlist) but not the last few ones.

Comment: I missed that comment, sorry - so if you replace the code in the question with https://jsfiddle.net/b2162w9L/ any difference?

Comment: `var Promise = require('promise');` this is setting yourself up for a world of pain - use native promises and if you want compatibility use bluebird. The `promise` package swallows errors.

Comment: I've just tried your code. What happens is only the 27th line in first file gets passed to the load.newload(transactionlist) 2213 times which is the same number of rows in the first file. I will update my question with the code for the load.newload function.

Comment: You should definitely clear the code up, so anyone can read this. Without passing 100 lines of code and with spaces formatted correctly. Then listen to the comments above. The Promise needs to be returned in order to correctly run `then` function. And also it's a good practice to use the native Promises as Benjamin has pointed out. If you clear these things up (even that comments look more annoying than useful) it'll be 200x clearer what you're asking.

Comment: question about `baby.parse` - does it call the `complete` callback only once?

Comment: @JaromandaX: it does it once per file that gets passed to it. I have found what's wrong. The problem lies in the load.newload function. It still had to wait on SQL to connect before inserting the data so it's like the incoming file function was passing it data faster than it can insert. So I changed the code around, and made sure SQL connection was established in the main app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be due to using a global variable `transactionlist` to share data among promises. Given its a case of chained promises, a better way to handle data  `transactionlist` could be to pass it along with return statement and let the next promise handle it without ambiguity (that it was updated or not).

This is how I'd do a chained promise.

```
var baby = require('babyparse');
var read = require('read-file');
var Promise = require('promise');
var load = require('../sql/insert');
// var transactionlist = [];
var incomingfile = function(file){
     //async load file and then parse after loading
        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              read( file, 'utf8', function (err, res){
              if (err) 
                {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log('Oops, an error occured while parsing the data: %s', err);
                }
              else {
                    resolve(res);
                    console.log(file);
               }
            });
        }).then(function (results){
                var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                baby.parse(results , {
                    dynamicTyping: true,
                    delimiter: "|",
                    complete: function (results, error) {
                        if(error)
                        {
                            console.log('Something went wrong');
                            reject(error);
                        }
                        else {
// define a local var here 
var transactionlist = [];

                                    for(i = 1; i < results.data.length - 1; i++)
                                {
                                    var transaction  = {
                                        column1 : results.data[i][14].substring(0, 6),
                                        column2: results.data[i][2].split(' ').join(''),
                                        column3: results.data[i][14].split(' ').join(''),
                                        column4: results.data[i][8],
                                        column5: results.data[i][9]
                                    }
                                transactionlist.push(transaction);

                                }//end for loop
// return transactionlist instead of updating global var
                                resolve([results, transactionlist]);
                                }
                        //console.log("Finished:", JSON.stringify(results.data));
                    }//end baby parse complete:function
                    });//end baby parse function
                }).then(function (results){
// load transactionlist again from passed values
var transactionlist = results[1];
results = results[0];
                    load.newload(transactionlist);
            });//end inner .then function
        });//end .then function
}//end incoming file function
```

I hope you can see the changes I made (they are not indented properly and commented). Using this method, you'd never miss data while using callbacks / promises.

Comment: Yeah, I'm chaining these promises. I've tried your above code. Yes, I do see the changes you've made. But it seems like this is causing the program to fetch a few lines from some files, when I checked the console, the problem is still there. It load.newload function gets called even before parsing the last 2 files is finished.

Comment: I've mixed your answer with the answer of Jaromanda and replaced "var promise = new promise..." with "return new promise...", and it's now just saving entries from the first file only.

Comment: Many thanks to your suggestion! I've actually used this and then tweaked my code to establish a connection to SQL in the main app.js. Now it works :D